# Search HTML iFrame with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, search, iframe, frame

I'm writing a website that displays the content of multiple html files in separate iFrames. I am hoping to integrate a search bar that searches the content of each iFrame and highlights the results (one at a time). 
Right now I am using a script from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/findpage.htm  :

```
/******************************************
* Find In Page Script -- Submitted/revised by Alan Koontz (alankoontz@REMOVETHISyahoo.com)
* Visit Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/) for full source code
* This notice must stay intact for use
******************************************/

//  revised by Alan Koontz -- May 2003

var TRange = null;
var dupeRange = null;
var TestRange = null;
var win = null;


//  SELECTED BROWSER SNIFFER COMPONENTS DOCUMENTED AT
//  http://www.mozilla.org/docs/web-developer/sniffer/browser_type.html

var nom = navigator.appName.toLowerCase();
var agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_major   = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
var is_minor   = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
var is_ie      = (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1);
var is_ie4up   = (is_ie && (is_major >= 4));
var is_not_moz = (agt.indexOf('netscape')!=-1)
var is_nav     = (nom.indexOf('netscape')!=-1);
var is_nav4    = (is_nav && (is_major == 4));
var is_mac     = (agt.indexOf("mac")!=-1);
var is_gecko   = (agt.indexOf('gecko') != -1);
var is_opera   = (agt.indexOf("opera") != -1);


//  GECKO REVISION

var is_rev=0
if (is_gecko) {
temp = agt.split("rv:")
is_rev = parseFloat(temp[1])
}


//  USE THE FOLLOWING VARIABLE TO CONFIGURE FRAMES TO SEARCH
//  (SELF OR CHILD FRAME)

//  If you want to search another frame, change from "self" to
//  the name of the target frame:
//  e.g., var frametosearch = 'main'

//var frametosearch = 'main';
var frametosearch = self;


function search(whichform, whichframe) {

//  TEST FOR IE5 FOR MAC (NO DOCUMENTATION)

if (is_ie4up && is_mac) return;

//  TEST FOR NAV 6 (NO DOCUMENTATION)

if (is_gecko && (is_rev <1)) return;

//  TEST FOR Opera (NO DOCUMENTATION)

if (is_opera) return;

//  INITIALIZATIONS FOR FIND-IN-PAGE SEARCHES

if(whichform.findthis.value!=null && whichform.findthis.value!='') {

       str = whichform.findthis.value;
       win = whichframe;
       var frameval=false;
       if(win!=self)
{

       frameval=true;  // this will enable Nav7 to search child frame
     win = parent.frames[whichframe];
        // win = document.getElementsByName('index');
}

}

else return;  //  i.e., no search string was entered

var strFound;

//  NAVIGATOR 4 SPECIFIC CODE

if(is_nav4 && (is_minor < 5)) {

  strFound=win.find(str); // case insensitive, forward search by default

//  There are 3 arguments available:
//  searchString: type string and it's the item to be searched
//  caseSensitive: boolean -- is search case sensitive?
//  backwards: boolean --should we also search backwards?
//  strFound=win.find(str, false, false) is the explicit
//  version of the above
//  The Mac version of Nav4 has wrapAround, but
//  cannot be specified in JS


        }

//  NAVIGATOR 7 and Mozilla rev 1+ SPECIFIC CODE (WILL NOT WORK WITH NAVIGATOR 6)

if (is_gecko && (is_rev >= 1)) {

    if(frameval!=false) win.focus(); // force search in specified child frame
    strFound=win.find(str, false, false, true, false, frameval, false);

//  The following statement enables reversion of focus 
//  back to the search box after each search event 
//  allowing the user to press the ENTER key instead
//  of clicking the search button to continue search.
//  Note: tends to be buggy in Mozilla as of 1.3.1
//  (see www.mozilla.org) so is excluded from users 
//  of that browser.

    if (is_not_moz)  whichform.findthis.focus();

//  There are 7 arguments available:
//  searchString: type string and it's the item to be searched
//  caseSensitive: boolean -- is search case sensitive?
//  backwards: boolean --should we also search backwards?
//  wrapAround: boolean -- should we wrap the search?
//  wholeWord: boolean: should we search only for whole words
//  searchInFrames: boolean -- should we search in frames?
//  showDialog: boolean -- should we show the Find Dialog?


}

 if (is_ie4up) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE revised 5/21/03

  if (TRange!=null) {

   TestRange=win.document.body.createTextRange();



   if (dupeRange.inRange(TestRange)) {

   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
    if (strFound) {
        //the following line added by Mike and Susan Keenan, 7 June 2003
        win.document.body.scrollTop = win.document.body.scrollTop + TRange.offsetTop;
        TRange.select();
        }


   }

   else {

     TRange=win.document.body.createTextRange();
     TRange.collapse(false);
     strFound=TRange.findText(str);
     if (strFound) {
        //the following line added by Mike and Susan Keenan, 7 June 2003
        win.document.body.scrollTop = TRange.offsetTop;
        TRange.select();
        }



   }
  }

   if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=win.document.body.createTextRange();
   dupeRange = TRange.duplicate();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
    if (strFound) {
        //the following line added by Mike and Susan Keenan, 7 June 2003
        win.document.body.scrollTop = TRange.offsetTop;
        TRange.select();
        }


   }

 }

  if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!") // string not found


}
// -->
</script>

<!--  EXAMPLE FORM OF FIND-IN-PAGE SEARCH USING SUBMIT (ALLOWING 'ENTER/RETURN' KEY PRESS EVENT) -->
<form name="form1" onSubmit="search(document.form1, frametosearch); return false"><input type="text" name="findthis" size="15" title="Press 'ALT s' after clicking submit to repeatedly search page"> <input type="submit" value="Find in Page" ACCESSKEY="s"></form>
```

Every time I press search, a pop-up is displayed that says the string cannot be found. I thought the error was due to naming however the iFrame to be searched is named "frametosearch". Are the lack of results due using iFrames rather than Frames?

Edit: I have also tried naming my iFrame as "index" and have changed "var frametosearch=self" in the script to all denominations of "index", including index, 'index', and "index" to no avail. I've also tried changing the onSubmit for the search bar to "search(document.form1, index)" and have had no luck